# Sum 2 different columns from 2 different tables with postgress

Tags: postgresql, union

I have created a query that sums up values from 2 different columns from 2 different tables:

```
'SELECT SUM (sum) AS income FROM incomes where company_id = $1 AND income_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3 
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM (sum) AS total_outcome FROM outcomes where company_id = $1 AND outcome_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3',
[company_id, start, end]
```

my problem is that the two resuls are coming back like this :

```
[
{income: "55"},
{income: "33"}
]
```

My expected result is :

```
[
{income: "55"},
{outcome: "33"}
]
```

looks like postgress is ignoring the second "AS" :/

Comment: as "incomes" and not as "incomes", i don't undestand it

Comment: You want to get a JSON array or what is this? Your requirement is completely unclear at the moment. Postgres is not ignoring a column header because you only can have one for a single column which you are creating at the moment. You are not creating an array or a JSON object or two columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL` adds rows, not columns. So, you get two rows in one column instead of two columns in one row. The row name is defined by the first `SELECT` statement.

You could do something like that:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM (sum) FROM incomes where company_id = $1 AND income_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3) as income,
    (SELECT SUM (sum) FROM outcomes where company_id = $1 AND outcome_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3) as total_outcome
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I'd appreciate if you could upvote as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns a single column and a single column can only have a single name.

If you want to identify the "source" of the value, you need to add another column

```
SELECT 'income' as source, SUM (sum) AS value
FROM incomes 
where company_id = $1 
  AND income_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total_outcome', SUM (sum) 
FROM outcomes 
where company_id = $1 
  AND outcome_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3
```